# Using Azure resources, how do I set up a redirect from myshortUrl.example/5 to myreallylongurl.example/a/5?

Tags: azure, dns

I have a long domain name, and want to be able to give out a shortened version which redirects to the long domain name. I am using an App Service for this the long domain hosting.

However, I also need to redirect to a specific folder on the server.

So `MyShortUrl.example/12345` should map to `MyLongUrl.example/mydirectory/12345`.

I don't think that this can be done through DNS alone, as the directory mapping is required, so it is modifying the original url, not just forwarding it.

It seems like an overkill to set up a new app service (mvc website) just to forward traffic.

Comment: care to tell which service are you using at the very least?

Comment: @4c74356b41 It's just a typical app service.

Comment: You are right, "redirection" is a feature that has no sense/does not exist at the DNS level, this is only an HTTP level feature. In the DNS you need to configure things so that the hostname `MyShortUrl.example` is mapped to some IP addresses on which you have  a listening webserver that will receive the URL `http://MyShortUrl.example/12345` (but remember to take care of HTTPS also) and that will be able to reply on the HTTP level with a code 301 or 302 to signal a redirection, with the new URL to contact. So you have also a webserver to configure somewhere to do this.

Comment: The problem would be the same even if no "directory mapping". If you need to redirect `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.net/` (even without any local path), you need an HTTP server somewhere that does the HTTP level redirection.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Mission Accomplished, in just a few lines of code!

Using an Azure Function:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
        TraceWriter log, string path)
{
    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://5-15GlobalEnergy.it/associate/" + path);  
    return response; 
}
```

Blog Post on the full details [here](https://blog.jonstodle.com/building-a-redirecter-with-airtable-and-azure-functions/)